# Разделение власти между бизнес-логикой и логикой приложения

Tags: java, архитектура

> Entities инкапсулируют логику бизнеса, то есть всё то, что не зависит от конкретного приложения, а будет общим для многих. Но если у вас отдельное приложение и оно не заточено под какой-то существующий бизнес, то Entities будут являться бизнес-объектами приложения, содержащими самые общие и высокоуровневые правила. 
>   ...
>   Кроме того, когда приложение отдельное, то надо стараться находить и выделять в Entities высокоуровневую логику из слоя UseCases, где зачастую она оседает по ошибке.

[источник](https://habr.com/company/mobileup/blog/335382/)

Приложение - простейший таймер. Функционал - старт, пауза и стоп. В репозитории сохраняю его состояние - `finishTime` (временная метка срабатывания таймера в будущем) и `remainingAfterPause` (время, остававшиеся до окончания работы таймера на момент паузы). Если `finishTime` и `remainedAfterPause` равны, к примеру, -1, то это означает что таймер остановлен. Взаимодействие с ОС обеспечивается объектом, реализующим интерфейс `SystemAlarm`.

```
interface SystemTimer {
    void setFinishTime(long finishTime);
    void cancel();
    long now(); // возвращает текущий момент времени
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, надо реализовать следующие UseCase-ы - `StartTimer`, `PauseTimer`, `StopTimer` и `TimerPresenterMediator`. `TimerPresenterMediator` реализует интерфейсы `TimerStateListener` и `PresenterListener` и отвечает за загрузку таймера из репозитория, указание презентеру состояния таймера и "тики" таймера, если последний пребывает в рабочем состоянии и экран с обратным отсчётом на переднем плане.

```
interface TimerStateListener {
   void onTimerStateChanged();
}

inteface PresenterListener {
    void onTimerScreenVisible();
    void onTimerScreenGone();
}
```

Старт таймера осуществляется следующим образом:

```
if(isRunning()) { throw new IllegalStateError(" ... ") }

if(isPaused()) {
    finishTime = systemAlarm.now() + remainedAfterPause;
    remainedAfterPause = -1;
}

if(isStopped()) {
    finishTime = systemAlarm.now() + duration;
}

systemAlarm.setFinishTime(finishTime);
repository.saveTimerState();
```

Для паузы и остановки код аналогичен.

Каким образом, следуя clean architecture, следует распределить код запуска таймера (паузы и остановки) между бизнес-логикой (enitity) и логикой-приложения (usecase)? Кто должен дергать `SystemAlarm` и `Repository`?

**Update**

Бизнес-логика — совокупность правил, принципов, зависимостей поведения объектов предметной области. Это с википедии, понадобилось время на осознание смысла этой фразы. Другими словами, наша бизнес-логика реагирует на воздействие со стороны прецедентов системы (usecases), проверяет допустимость изменения своего состояния и изменяет его (или выбрасывает исключение). Больше ничего она не делает. Исходя из этого, ответ на поставленный вопрос можно считать очевидным - никаких `SystemAlarm` и `Repository` здесь быть не может.

Comment: ответ на поставленный вопрос можно считать очевидным

Comment: Пример с таймером, имхо, не очень удачен - сложно представить себе таймер как бизнес сущность... разве что имеется в виду таймер на стадионе, который может управляться одной аппликухой, показываться другой (на табло) и рендериться в веб приложении или читаться через апи итд. Тогда да, ни о каких SystemAlarm итд не может быть и речи.